# Which FontAwesome package do I need to download to use on my own server?

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I would like to use FontAwesome in a WordPress theme for social media icons but I want to have all the FontAwesome files on my own server in a separate folder like /theme/assets/fonts/..Which Font Awesome package do I need, the web or the desktop one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always get confused by FontAwesome terminology aswell, but this is what you should use https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself (which is the web version). The only thing left for you to choose form is if you want it in SVG version of standard font. That's totally up to you